# Adding several URIs to SOAP Envelope using Java

Tags: java, soap

I am trying to write a SOAP pull. I am running into difficulty formatting the message correctly.

I am only using the included javax.xml.soap.* library with Exclipse

I need the Envelope to have multiple URIs in it. This is the example provided for use with SOAPUI.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sh="http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh" xmlns:user="http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh/userdata" xmlns:ser="http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh/servicedata">
```

However after looking through several tutorials I am only able to produce

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sh="http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh">
```

I have haven't been able to find any documentation on how to achieve the required output. I am still new to SOAP and Java so I am not sure how to articulate exactly what I need.

Here is the code I have so far minus the child element portion

```
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setPrefix("soapenv");
    soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV");
    soapMessage.getSOAPBody().setPrefix("soapenv");
    soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().setPrefix("soapenv"); 

    String serverURI = "http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("sh", serverURI );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get this soap-envelope,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sh="http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh" xmlns:user="http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh/userdata" xmlns:ser="http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh/servicedata">
```

Just add addNamespaceDeclaration after your code like this.

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("sh", serverURI );

//added code here
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("user", "http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh/userdata" );
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ser", "http://www.website.com/ems/soap/sh/servicedata" );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I was looking for. I voted up your answer.

Comment: No idea why, but keep getting a `org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.` for this...